# DBContext is null when getting in implementation of IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have made an implementation of IHostedService where I will load a cache when my application is starting up. In that implementation of IHostedService I need the Context for the DB, but it is null when I try to get it.

I am loading my service in StartUp ConfigureServices in the last line:

```
   services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));

   ...

   services.AddHostedService<InitializeCacheService>();
```

And my service look like this (I am getting the cache but not the context):

```
public class InitializeCacheService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    public InitializeCacheService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this._scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
            CacheLogic cacheLogic = new CacheLogic(cache, context);
            cacheLogic.LoadProfileCache();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks very much in advance :-)

**UPDATE**
This is actually working, the problem is that I missed the initialization of the context in CacheLogic :-| Sorry about that!

But now it is working then i get the error below when I query in CacheLogic, an that might be because it is async and I handle over the Context in a time limited scope in the InitializeCacheService?

But After rethinking my solution I think that the CacheLogic shall be a singleton, and then my problem is how to get access to cache and DBContext in a singleton (I will create a new question for that).

*System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'*

Comment: I can't really see anything from the code you have shown. Seems to be in order. I would recommend you to share the entire solution on Github or similar. I can't see anything from what you have shared.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! But if I have don it right, what can be the causes for the context is null?

Comment: My guess is something in startup not setup right. Or maybe the DB context not made right. But can only guess without seeing all the code.

Comment: What's the use of this `InitializeCacheService`? Only for testing? Anyway, you're supposed to obtain a context by dependency injection, not by using the dependency container as a service locator. I.e. `InitializeCacheService` constructor should have both dependencies as constructor arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. InitializeCacheService is used for loading a cache with data from the DB when the api is started. If I try to obtain the context from the constructor like I do other places the application is throwing exception when starting up: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot consume scoped service 'DAL.MyContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor'.'

Comment: @PNR what is null when you try to get it? `InitializeCacheService`? `MyDbContext`? `IMemoryCache`? `GetRequiredService` will throw if the service isn't registered so MyContext can't be null. You didn't post any code that adds memory caching, so `GetService<IMemoryCache>` will always be null.

Comment: @PNR post the *rest* of your Startup.cs, specifically the parts that set up memory caching.